# Using SUM in an SQL query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do a query where it adds up the totals for the orders from each customer.

I have tried a few different ways but I am not sure the right way to do it.

I've tried...

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
SUM(Total) as Totals
COUNT(OrderID) as OrderAmt
GROUP BY CustomerID, OrderAmt, ShipName, Totals
```

I want to get this result....

```
=====================================
|CustomerID|Orders |ShipName|Total  |
|==========|=======|========|=======|
|3334      |3      |Joe Blow|1100.00|
|----------|-------|--------|-------|
|114       |2      |Steve   |280.00 |
|----------|-------|--------|-------|
|1221      |1      |Sue     |250.00 |
|----------|-------|--------|-------|
|3444      |1      |Bob     |22.00  |
=====================================
```

From this table...

```
|===================================|
|CustomerID|OrderID|ShipName|Total  |
|==========|=======|========|=======|
|3334      |232    |Joe Blow|400.00 |
|----------|-------|--------|-------|
|3334      |234    |Joe Blow|500.00 |
|----------|-------|--------|-------|
|3334      |231    |Joe Blow|200.00 |
|----------|-------|--------|-------|
|114       |235    |Steve   |250.00 |
|----------|-------|--------|-------|
|114       |239    |Steve   |30.00  |
|----------|-------|--------|-------|
|1221      |244    |Sue     |250.00 |
|----------|-------|--------|-------|
|3444      |632    |Bob     |22.00  |
|===================================|
```

What would be the correct SQL statement for this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Sum` and `count` can be used to get the result you want:

```
select CustomerID, count(*) as Orders, ShipName, sum(Total) as Total
from Table
group by CustomerID, ShipName
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: +1 for even taking the time to answer when it appears the OP didn't try anything

Answer (score 2):

```
select CustomerID, count(OrderID) Orders, ShipName, sum(Total) Total
from Order_TAB
group by CustomerID, ShipName
```