# CakePHP: Cannot determine the total working hours of employees

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

**What I want:-** I want to calculate the total working hours of my employees based on the working hours of multiple days.

**My problem** the total working hours ($total_hours) is not working.

## My Model

> class Attendence extends AppModel {
>
> ```
> function add($data){
>     if (!empty($data)) {
>         $this->create();
>         if($this->save($data)) {
>             return true ;
>
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> function fetchdata() {
>     return $this->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Attendence.date' > '2014-04-01',
>         'AND' => array('Attendences.date' < '2014-04-21'),
>
>            )));
>
>
>           }
> ```
>
> }

## My Controller

> class EmployeesController extends AppController {
>
> ```
> public $uses = array('Employee', 'Attendence', 'InsertDate');
> public function add()
> {
>
>
>     if($this->Employee->add($this->request->data)==true){
>         $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
>     }
>
>
> }
>
>  public function index(){
>     $this->set('employees',$this->Employee->Fetch());
>      $this->set('attendence',$this->Attendence->fetchdata());
>      $this->set('dates',$this->InsertDate->fetchdate());
> }
> ```
>
> }

## My View

```
<div class="index">
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Num</th>
    <th>Employee</th>
    <th>Salary/Hour</th>
    <th>Start Date</th>
    <th>End Date</th>
    <th>Total Hour</th>
    <th>Total Salary</th>
    </thead>

<?php
$id = 0;
foreach($employees as $e):?>
 <? $id++ ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $e{'Employee'}{'id'} ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $e['Employee']['firstname'], $e['Employee']['lastname'] ?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $e['Employee']['salary'] ?></td>'


<?php  foreach($dates as $d):?>

            <td><?php echo $d['InsertDate']['start_date'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $d['InsertDate']['end_date'] ?></td>





    <?php
        $total_hours = 0;
        foreach ($attendence as $et){
            $ts1 = strtotime($et['Attendence']['in_time']);
            $ts2 = strtotime($et['Attendence']['out_time']);
            $diff = abs($ts1 - $ts2) / 3600;
            $total_hours += number_format($diff,2);

          }
          //Total hours

          echo '<td style="text-align:center">'.$total_hours.'</td>';

          //Total Salary
          echo '<td style="text-align:center">'.$total_hours*$e['Employee']['salary'].'</td>';



          ?>
          <?php endforeach; ?>


          <?php endforeach; ?>

          </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

### A programmer friend of mine gave me a solution. But I dont know how to implement in CAKEPHP

I am updating the solution also

Look at here :

> $total_hours = 0;
>           foreach ($attendence as $et){
>                 $ts1 = strtotime($et['Attendence']['in_time']);
>                 $ts2 = strtotime($et['Attendence']['out_time']);
>                 $diff = abs($ts1 - $ts2) / 3600;
>                 $total_hours += number_format($diff,2);
>
> ```
>       }
> ```

The code shows you that there is an array. the array contains (attendance id and in_time and out_time in each point).
The Important thing is  you should check how you fill this array.
In the above foreach that you generate the table by $employees array , you have the (employee_id) wich name (id) here
So you should write a new query in your view!!!In the middle of your first foreach and before second foreach
before this line :

> $total_hours = 0

You have to write a query and fetch data from DB like this :

```
//SELECT * FROM attendences
    WHERE attendences.date > '2014-04-23' AND attendences.date < '2014-04-30'
    AND id=$e['Employee']['id'] // is your employee_id in your first array.
```

So when you fetched data , You have a new array named "$attendence"
Then , your second foreach(which calculates the salary and total hours) should work correctly

Comment: plz, update your question with few data from tables...

Comment: Your friend gave you a weird solution... Use the DB for that simple task, mysql sum(). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574721/using-sum-in-an-sql-query

Comment: Yes it's easier.... it worked