# SQL statement, result from different row

Tags: sql

I have a sales table that look like this

```
receipt saletype qtysold sellprice discount
31103  -----   I   --------- 1 -------   39 ------- 0
31103  ----   W   -------- 1 --------    0 ------- 14
31103  -----   I   --------- 1 -------   39 ------- 0
31103  ----  W   -------- 1 --------    0 ------- 14
```

The actual qtysold is 2 pcs from this receipt 31103.

I am trying to get the result from qtysold where salestype='I'
My result will be incorrect when I do this

```
Select qtysold, sellprice, discount
from salestable
where receipt = '31103'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using SUM in an SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574721/using-sum-in-an-sql-query)

Comment: How about including `and salestype = 'I'` in the `where` clause?

Comment: Hi Gordon, I am not able to cause discount is in salestype W and I would need that to be displayed in the result.

Comment: @louise: can you specify which database you are using?  Also, there seems to be a bit of confusion about what you really want.  To help us out, pretend you have a working query, and post what the results of your ideal query would look like. So that would include, not just qtysold, but all other columns you want as well.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, when i'm trying to reply.

Comment: I am also unsure where to start, i'm confusing myself too. So I started a new question with clearer table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30971716/sql-getting-result-from-different-columns

Answer (score 0):

You can easily return all rows with salestype = 'I' by including this filter in your where clause.  To include multiple filters in a single where clause, you would need the 'and' keyword.  The code would look something like this-

```
Select qtysold, sellprice, discount
from salestable
where receipt = '31103'
and salestype = 'I'
```

Comment: I am not able to because the discount is in salestype W and I will need that to be displayed.

Comment: @louise so you want the total quantity sold for I and W where receipt = 31103?