# SQL getting result from different columns

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the query to display the result as below but I am not able to do that.

`Salestable`:

```
receipt    product    saletype    qtysold    sellprice    discount
------------------------------------------------------------------
31103    - sugar  ------ I ------- 1 ------ 25 --------    0
31103    - sugar ------- W ------- 1 ------- 0 ---------   3
31103    - milk  ------- I ------- 1 ------ 39 --------    0
31103    - milk  ------- W ------  1 ------- 0 ---------   3
```

My query:

```
Select 
    receipt, product,
    qty sold, (where saletype='I')
    sellprice, (where saletype='I')
    discount (where salestype='W')
from 
    salestable
```

So that my result look like the below.

```
Receipt  Product  Qtysold Sellprice Discount
------------------------------------------------
31103  --- sugar ---- 1   ------ 25  --------- 3
31103  --- milk ------ 1  ------ 39---------- 14
```

Comment: Is your data always in pairs like that?

Comment: now i'm getting real close by using the below query.

Comment: Pardon me for it's not the actual table row name

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind this will only work if you have data in pairs. else you will have to adjust outer apply accordingly.

```
Select a.receipt, a.product, x.QtySold, x.SellPrice, y.discount
(
 select distinct receipt, product from salestable
) a 
outer apply (
  Select B.QtySold, B.SellPrice from salestable B WHERE A.receipt = B.receipt AND A.product = B.product AND b.SALETYPE = 'I'
) x

outer apply (
 Select B.discount  from salestable B WHERE A.receipt = B.receipt AND A.product = B.product AND b.SALETYPE = 'W'
) y
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're on the right track.

```
select
receipt,
product,
max(case when salestype='I' then sellprice else null end) as SellPrice,
max(case when salestype ='I' then qty_sold else null end) as QtySold,
max(case when salestype = 'W' then discount else null end) as discount
from
salestable
group by 
receipt,
product
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this:

```
SELECT 
    receipt, product, 
    qtySold = SUM(CASE WHEN saletype = 'I' THEN qtySold ELSE 0 END),
    sellprice = SUM(CASE WHEN saletype = 'I' THEN sellprice ELSE 0 END),
    discount = SUM(CASE WHEN salestype = 'W' THEN discount ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
    salestable
GROUP BY
    receipt, product
```