# SQL total up certain element in a column to create another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure the title for this question, i just want to achieve something like below, if there is already an answer, please kindly provide me the link or provide the search tag, so i got a direction to what i'm looking for.

I have a table like below,
Table 1
date       |payname |type|amount|ID
2017/07/01 |Cash    | c  |100   | A1
2017/07/01 |Cash    | c  |200   | A1
2017/07/01 |USD     | f  |200   | A1
2017/07/01 |SGD     | f  |100   | A1
2017/07/01 |USD     | f  |100   | A1
2017/07/01 |Yen     | f  |200   | A1
2017/07/02 |USD     | f  |200   | A1
2017/07/02 |SGD     | f  |400   | A1
2017/07/02 |WON     | f  |300   | A1
2017/07/02 |Cash    | c  |100   | A1
2017/07/02 |Cash    | c  |300   | A1
2017/07/02 |Cash    | c  |200   | A1

TAble 2
date       |C.Cards|ID
2017/07/01 |100         | A1
2017/07/01 |200         | A1
2017/07/01 |300         | A1
2017/07/01 |100         | A1
2017/07/01 |200         | A1
2017/07/01 |300         | A1
2017/07/02 |100         | A1
2017/07/02 |100         | A1
2017/07/02 |200         | A1
2017/07/02 |100         | A1
2017/07/02 |200         | A1
2017/07/02 |100         | A1

Expected Result
date       |Cash|Cash-Forex|C.Cards
2017/07/01 |300 | 600      | 1200
2017/07/02 |600 | 900      | 800

Expected result table
1. Date column, grouped by of table 1 & 2 date column
2. cash column, sum of table 1 type of 'c'
3. cash-forex column, sum of table type of 'f'
4. c.cards column, sum of table 2 c.cards column

I'm able to generate expected result table, date & cash & cash-forex column, but when i try to join table to generate c.cards column, i can't find the expected answer....please help me guys, thanks!

Comment: Please check out this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574721/using-sum-in-an-sql-query Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using the `conditional aggregation` method

```
select sum(case when type = 'C' then amount else  0 end) as cash,
       sum(case when type = 'F' then amount else  0 end) as [Cash-Forex]
From Yourtable
```

`case` statement inside the `sum` aggregate will consider the `amount` based on the mentioned `type`

Comment: Hi Sir, i have just modified my question, could you please take a look at it, and provide me the correct query? the first 3 column i generated using your query above...but when i try to join table to generate 1 more column, i didnt get the expected answer...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can Achieve this Using IIF (IIF is a SQL2012 feature.)

```
    select 
         sum(iif(type = 'C' ,amount,0 )) as cash,
         sum(iif(type = 'F' ,amount,0 )) as [Cash-Forex]
    From Yourtable
```